# Confirmation after server side validation Struts 1

Tags: html, forms, jsp, struts, action

I've been doing a lot of research for this solution but it seems that most answers are in ASP.NET. I am using the html:form tag within my JSP. What I am trying to achieve is showing a simple JavaScript confirmation box after the server side validation is done for my html form. I have it in place but it's showing before the validation. I'm doing my server side validations within my submit action, if it pass it goes to the next page and if it doesn't I am using "find.inputForward" to reload the page with the validation errors. What I would like to happen is to somehow show a confirmation right after my validations are done within my submit action. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance

**Update**
My Server side validations is working, I just need some way to trigger a confirmation message once the validations has passed before the action is called to submit the information to the database

**Update**
Im required to have a confirmation message shown before the data is sent to the DB. I have a confirmation box but it is showing before the validations. The user should be shown a confirmation box after the validations and before the information is sent to the DB

Here is a sample of what I have:

JavaScript:

```
function confirmAdd()
    {return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this name?');}
```

HTML:

```
<html:form method="post" action="/myAction/submitName.action?method=submitNameForm">

<label for="name"><Please enter your name</label>

<html:text property="name"  styleId="name" name="myFormBean" maxlength="10" size="10" html:text>

<input type="submit"  value="Add Name"  tabindex="1" onClick="return confirmAdd();">    

</html:form>
```

Struts Action Mapping:

```
<action path="/addName" 
    type="myAction.submitName" 
    input="/homepage.jsp" 
    scope="request" 
    parameter="method" name="myFormBean"> 
    <forward name="Success" path="/myConfirmationPage.jsp"/> 
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should do server-side validation after submitting a form and javascript validation (optional) before.
Another option is to use ajax for server-side validation before submitting a form.

Comment: The server side validation is happening after the form submission, if the validation pass I want a confirmation box to show before the action, before the information is submitted to the database

Comment: You said in the question: "What I am trying to achieve is showing a simple JavaScript confirmation box after the server side validation is done for my html form." So before or after?

Comment: I'm sorry if Im not clear. I want the confirmation shown after the validation

Comment: If you need to use server-side pre-validation before you submit a form, use Ajax but then you should still validate again. Or use javascript PRE-validation instead of Ajax.

Comment: The information that's getting validated is from the backend, checking to see if the name already exists

Comment: My server side validation is checking if the name exist, I need a way to tell the front end the validations passed

Comment: @user2069471 What's the point? If the validation passes and the information is put into the DB, just tell the user the validations passed and the information has been saved. What's the specific problem?

Comment: @DaveNewton Im required to have a confirmation message shown before the data is sent to the DB. I have a confirmation box but it is showing before the validations. The user should be shown a confirmation box after the validations and before the information is sent to the DB.

Comment: @user2069471 Why? Can the user *do* anything with that information? In other words, is it a "Validation has passed, hit [Cancel] to abort save" type thing? If not, then who cares when *precisely* it's shown to the user?

Comment: @DaveNewton This is just the proper way it's suppose to done, this is required by the client, Yes, if the user hit ok, proceed with the transaction, if the user hit cancel it will not proceed with the transaction

Comment: @user2069471 Then you'll either need to use Ajax/JavaScript, or keep the form bean in session (or duplicate the data), or use a "two-stage" process where a record is created but not marked as "inserted" or some other way of storing a temporary record.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you give me an example how would I use Ajax/Javascript in the action class and jsp in this situation?